# How do you say "Listen to you play" or "Watch you work"?

Tags: перевод

I always get tripped up trying to say simple things like these in Russian:

- I like listening to you speak.
- I like watching you work.
- I'd like to watch you play a videogame.

I usually start to say:

- Я люблю слушать...*(неловкая пауза)*...когда/пока ты говоришь.
- Я люблю смотреть когда ты работаешь.
- Я хотел бы смотреть... *(совсем не знаю!)*

These always sounds very awkward and incorrect to me. Is there an alternative, simple and informal construction that might help me avoid getting stuck like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Универсальное слово "как" подойдет сюда.

```
Я люблю слушать, как ты говоришь.
Я люблю смотреть, как ты работаешь.
Я бы посмотрел, как ты играешь в игры
(Я бы хотел смотреть, как ты играешь в игры)
```

Comment: Интересно. Если так, то как перевести "I like listening to **how** you play" или "I want to watch **how** you work"?

Comment: Я думаю в этом случае это будет зависеть от интонации. Кстати в форумах очень часто можно увидеть что слово КАК написано большими буквами. Это как раз тот самый случай когда автор хочет подчеркнуть что ему именно нравится то, КАК кто-то делает. Кстати в русском языке нужно ставить запятую перед как, так ка это становится сложно-подчиненным предолжением

Comment: Можно кстати усилить КАК используя слово ТО, например: `Я люблю слушать то, как ты говоришь`

Comment: Конечно! Я много раз встречал с этой зависимостью от интонации в контексте слова "что". (И в книгах, оно пишется с ударением в этих ситуациях.) Имеет смысл, что это так же само со словом "как". Спасибо!

Comment: А можно ещё немножко поменять грамматическую структуру (всё равно ведь она не как в английском) и сказать "Я люблю слушать твои речи/твой голос, Я люблю/хотел бы смотреть/посмотреть на тебя, когда ты работаешь/играешь в видеоигру".

Comment: You forgot to include `хотел` in your last translation. Should have been `Я хотел бы посмотрел, как ты играешь в игры` additionally original is in a singular form, but translation is plural. It should be `в игру`

Comment: @SaUce: It really sounds better when you use "бы" or "б" in place of "хотел".

Comment: @Cha the way I used to say is `Я хочу увидеть как ты играешь в эту игру` or `Мне хотелось посмотреть как ты играешь в эту игру` You have to consider that Russians don't speak exactly the same through out Russia. When Moskvichi would come to Sibiria we could pick up on them really fast that they are not local.

Comment: OK, I have updated my answer. Thanks for your input

Answer (score 3):

cha's answer is just the way you do it! In Russian "как" is very productive for sentences describing perceiving someone/something performing an action. I.e. not only sentences like "I like listening to you singing", but also "I saw you waiting", "I heard you stumbling", "I watched you playing the concert" and so on.

Just use "I " + как + the action in present, as in:
*Люблю слушать, как ты говоришь.*
*Мне нравится слушать, как ты играешь на гитаре, когда одна.*
*Я видел (-а), как ты прошёл игру.*
*Хотел (хотела) бы посмотреть, как ты в неё играешь.* ("в неё" here is a reference to a previously mentioned game, for example)

As for "I like listening to **how** you play", you can use emphasis on *КАК* word in speech or rephrase to something more explicit, as in:
*Мне нравится, как ты играешь.*
*Интересно посмотреть за твоей работой — можно?* (~'It'd be interesting to watch you working - may I?')
*Можно посмотреть, как ты играешь?*
*Люблю твоё пение.*
*Мне нравится то, как ты читаешь стихи.*

Though, remember that the short variants "Люблю, как ты поёшь" sound more natural and colloquial than nouns ("Люблю твоё пение"), and in some cases much more natural ("Люблю твоё чтение стихов" - meh). Not for every possible activity a good deverbal noun exists that doesn't sound stilted. Inserting "то, как" for no real reason will also make it slightly mor bookish (I am not referring to the cases where "то" cannot be omitted). All these phrases are more or less similar in general meaning.

So you can always make the meaning clear in further conversation. E.g. "У тебя хорошо получается", "У тебя приятный мелодичный голос", "Я вряд ли так смогу", "Никогда не умела" and so on.

Comment: Thank you! This a very informative followup. Unfortunately, I don't have enough reputation yet to upvote you, but I will when I can!

Comment: +1 for an explanation in English. My russian is far too basic to read Q&As written without any of my native tongue :)